# Magento 2 How to check if customer address is deleted via Admin?

Tags: magento2, admin, event-observer, customer, customer-address

Here is the scenario I want to achieve.

Steps:

1. Login to Admin.
2. Click on Edit link of any customer.
3. Go to Address tab.
4. Delete an Address.
5. Click on Save.

After these steps I want to add an entry to my custom table if the address is deleted.

How can I check if the address is deleted using `adminhtml_customer_save_after` event?

```
$customerObj = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->load($customer_id);
foreach ($customerObj->getAddresses() as $address) {
    $customerAddress[] = $address->toArray();
    $customerAddressObj[] = $address;
}
$customerAddressCount = count($customerAddress);
```

This returns 2 if customer has 2 address in `customer_address_entity` table.
How can I check if the $customerAddressCount is reduced?

Or Any other approach?

Comment: you need to create plugin functionality of this event in your custom extension, So when admin remove address your code called.

Comment: I have that code ready. I just want to know how can I detect if the address is deleted.

Comment: did you get a solution?